# Internet access through ASA firewall

Tags: cisco-asa, firewall

I am new to ASA firewall. I have ASA 5520 firewall (hardware) I want my clients in my Local network to gain internet access through the firewall. So it should be like this:
ISP to Billion modem to Firewall (hardware) to Switch to client.

Comment: What is your question? I have read the question several times, but I don't find an actual question.

Comment: I want the clients in my network to gain internet access through the firewall.

Comment: OK, that is a statement of your goal, but what is your specific question? You need to edit the question with your question, and include the sanitized ASA configuration, pointing out where you think you have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

though your question is really vague I think you should do source NAT for internet access for your clients (aka MASQUERADE)

imagine your client network 192.168.1.0 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0

you should config this with CLI (supposing you have configured everthing else such as interfaces and security-levels etc) :

```
object network myclients
 subnet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
```

reference :http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa83/configuration/guide/config/nat_objects.html